# Data from MySQL database not showing in PyQt5's QTableWidget

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours, but even with the fixes found on other similar questions, my QTableWidget only shows column/rows and the cells stay empty.

My code (removed some parts to make more readable):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QErrorMessage, QMessageBox, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QWidget, QTableView, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView
import mysql.connector
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

# Connection to my database
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    database="autonoleggio"
)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_mostra.clicked.connect(self.MostraListaCategoria)

    def MostraListaCategoria(self):
        mycursor.execute("select * from categoria")
        risultati = mycursor.fetchall()
        self.table_categoria.setRowCount(len(risultati))
        self.table_categoria.setColumnCount(5)
        self.table_categoria.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Id", "Descrizione", "Prezzo giorn.", "Prezzo sett.", "Prezzo mensile"])
        self.table_categoria.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) 
        self.table_categoria.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        rowcount = 0
        while True:
            sqlRow = mycursor.fetchone()
            if sqlRow == None:
                break
            for col in range(0, 5): 
                self.table_categoria.setItem(rowcount, col, sqlRow[col])
            rowcount += 1

        
def main():
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the .ui file from Qt Creator converted into .py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1030, 621)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.Categoria = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Categoria.setObjectName("Categoria")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Categoria)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 331, 157))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_id = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_id.setObjectName("label_id")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_id)
        self.insert_id = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.insert_id.setObjectName("insert_id")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_id)
        self.label_descrizione = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_descrizione.setObjectName("label_descrizione")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_descrizione)
        self.insert_descrizione = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.insert_descrizione.setObjectName("insert_descrizione")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_descrizione)
        self.label_prezzo_giornaliero = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_prezzo_giornaliero.setObjectName("label_prezzo_giornaliero")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_prezzo_giornaliero)
        self.insert_prezzo_giornaliero = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.insert_prezzo_giornaliero.setObjectName("insert_prezzo_giornaliero")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_prezzo_giornaliero)
        self.label_prezzo_settimanale = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_prezzo_settimanale.setObjectName("label_prezzo_settimanale")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_prezzo_settimanale)
        self.insert_prezzo_settimanale = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.insert_prezzo_settimanale.setObjectName("insert_prezzo_settimanale")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_prezzo_settimanale)
        self.label_prezzo_mensile = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_prezzo_mensile.setObjectName("label_prezzo_mensile")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_prezzo_mensile)
        self.insert_prezzo_mensile = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.insert_prezzo_mensile.setObjectName("insert_prezzo_mensile")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_prezzo_mensile)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Categoria)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 10, 171, 205))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.btn_aggiungi = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_aggiungi.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_aggiungi.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_aggiungi.setCheckable(False)
        self.btn_aggiungi.setObjectName("btn_aggiungi")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_aggiungi)
        self.btn_rimuovi = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_rimuovi.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_rimuovi.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_rimuovi.setCheckable(False)
        self.btn_rimuovi.setObjectName("btn_rimuovi")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_rimuovi)
        self.btn_modifica = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_modifica.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_modifica.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_modifica.setCheckable(False)
        self.btn_modifica.setObjectName("btn_modifica")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_modifica)
        self.btn_mostra = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_mostra.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_mostra.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_mostra.setCheckable(False)
        self.btn_mostra.setObjectName("btn_mostra")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_mostra)
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Categoria)
        self.btn_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 180, 93, 28))
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.insert_cerca = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.Categoria)
        self.insert_cerca.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 270, 161, 22))
        self.insert_cerca.setObjectName("insert_cerca")
        self.btn_cerca = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Categoria)
        self.btn_cerca.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 300, 93, 28))
        self.btn_cerca.setObjectName("btn_cerca")
        self.table_categoria = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.Categoria)
        self.table_categoria.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 270, 751, 241))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.table_categoria.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.table_categoria.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.table_categoria.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.table_categoria.setObjectName("table_categoria")
        self.table_categoria.setColumnCount(0)
        self.table_categoria.setRowCount(0)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Categoria, "")
        self.Noleggio = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Noleggio.setObjectName("Noleggio")
        self.formLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Noleggio)
        self.formLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 391, 261))
        self.formLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget_2")
        self.formNoleggio = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.formNoleggio.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formNoleggio.setObjectName("formNoleggio")
        self.label_nome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_nome.setObjectName("label_nome")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_nome)
        self.label_cognome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_cognome.setObjectName("label_cognome")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_cognome)
        self.label_data_nascita = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_data_nascita.setObjectName("label_data_nascita")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_data_nascita)
        self.label_indirizzo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_indirizzo.setObjectName("label_indirizzo")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_indirizzo)
        self.label_carta_credito = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_carta_credito.setObjectName("label_carta_credito")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_carta_credito)
        self.label_data_inizio = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_data_inizio.setObjectName("label_data_inizio")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_data_inizio)
        self.label_data_fine = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_data_fine.setObjectName("label_data_fine")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_data_fine)
        self.label_targa = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_targa.setObjectName("label_targa")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_targa)
        self.insert_nome = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_nome.setObjectName("insert_nome")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_nome)
        self.insert_cognome = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_cognome.setObjectName("insert_cognome")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_cognome)
        self.insert_data_nascita = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_data_nascita.setObjectName("insert_data_nascita")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_data_nascita)
        self.insert_indirizzo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_indirizzo.setObjectName("insert_indirizzo")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_indirizzo)
        self.insert_carta_credito = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_carta_credito.setObjectName("insert_carta_credito")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_carta_credito)
        self.insert_targa = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_targa.setObjectName("insert_targa")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_targa)
        self.insert_data_inizio = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_data_inizio.setObjectName("insert_data_inizio")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_data_inizio)
        self.insert_data_fine = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.formLayoutWidget_2)
        self.insert_data_fine.setObjectName("insert_data_fine")
        self.formNoleggio.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.insert_data_fine)
        self.btn_conferma_noleggio = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Noleggio)
        self.btn_conferma_noleggio.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 320, 93, 28))
        self.btn_conferma_noleggio.setObjectName("btn_conferma_noleggio")
        self.btn_costo_noleggio = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Noleggio)
        self.btn_costo_noleggio.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 320, 93, 28))
        self.btn_costo_noleggio.setObjectName("btn_costo_noleggio")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Noleggio, "")
        self.Cronologia = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Cronologia.setObjectName("Cronologia")
        self.table_cronologia = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.Cronologia)
        self.table_cronologia.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 959, 451))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.table_cronologia.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.table_cronologia.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.table_cronologia.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.table_cronologia.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.table_cronologia.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.table_cronologia.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.table_cronologia.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.table_cronologia.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.table_cronologia.setColumnCount(5)
        self.table_cronologia.setObjectName("table_cronologia")
        self.table_cronologia.setRowCount(0)
        self.btn_aggiorna_cronologia = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Cronologia)
        self.btn_aggiorna_cronologia.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 480, 93, 28))
        self.btn_aggiorna_cronologia.setObjectName("btn_aggiorna_cronologia")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Cronologia, "")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1030, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuAutonoleggio = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAutonoleggio.setObjectName("menuAutonoleggio")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAutonoleggio.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_id.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        self.label_descrizione.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Descrizione"))
        self.label_prezzo_giornaliero.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Prezzo giornaliero"))
        self.label_prezzo_settimanale.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Prezzo settimanale"))
        self.label_prezzo_mensile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Prezzo mensile"))
        self.btn_aggiungi.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Aggiungi"))
        self.btn_rimuovi.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Rimuovi"))
        self.btn_modifica.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Modifica"))
        self.btn_mostra.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mostra tutto"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.insert_cerca.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cerca categoria..."))
        self.btn_cerca.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cerca"))
        self.table_categoria.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Categoria), _translate("MainWindow", "Categoria"))
        self.label_nome.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nome*"))
        self.label_cognome.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cognome*"))
        self.label_data_nascita.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data di nascita*(GG/MM/AAA)"))
        self.label_indirizzo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Indirizzo*"))
        self.label_carta_credito.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Carta di credito"))
        self.label_data_inizio.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data inizio noleggio*"))
        self.label_data_fine.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data fine noleggio*"))
        self.label_targa.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Targa*"))
        self.btn_conferma_noleggio.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Conferma"))
        self.btn_costo_noleggio.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Calcola costo"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Noleggio), _translate("MainWindow", "Noleggio"))
        self.table_cronologia.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.btn_aggiorna_cronologia.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Aggiorna"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Cronologia), _translate("MainWindow", "Cronologia"))
        self.menuAutonoleggio.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Autonoleggio"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to show the content of my database's "categoria" table into the QtableWidget ( called table_categoria) after pressing the "Mostra tutto" button.

I'm using Python 3.8.5 and PyQt5

Comment: [`setItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem) expects a QTableWidgetItem instance, not a string. Change that line to `self.table_categoria.setItem(rowcount, col, QTableWidgetItem(sqlRow[col]))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'd already tried that, but it doesn't seem to make any difference, result is still the same for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already used `fetchall()`, which will return **all** results of the query.

When you call `fetchone()` after that, it will return nothing as there are no more results available.

You should fill the table using `risultati`.

Also, [`setItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem) only accepts QTableWidgetItem instances, not strings.

Note that the default `QTableWidgetItem()` constructor only accepts *strings* for its value, so if you are using other data types (such as integers) you *must* set those data manually with the `Qt.DisplayRole` role.

```py
for rowcount, sqlRow in enumerate(risultati):
    for col, value in enumerate(sqlRow):
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, value)
        self.table_categoria.setItem(rowcount, col, item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I still can't seem to be able to fill all of the columns though. Now it's only printing data to my Descrizione column, leaving the other ones blank

Comment: Yes, it's just in the QtableWidget that they don't show. I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm very new at programming

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(risultati[:2])`? Note, the *exact* output.

Comment: The exact output is: [(1, 'utilitaria', 8, 44, 140), (2, 'monovolume', 10, 55, 150)]

Comment: As I thought. Those are *integer* values, and QTableWidgetItem only accepts strings for its base constructor. See the update.

Comment: Oooh, makes sense. It's working perfectly now, thanks a lot for the help! Grazie mille ;)